# How to retrieve result from WebService response?

Tags: web-services

I am new to WebService. I am getting the following response from the WebService

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>    
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">        
<S:Header/>    
<S:Body><ns2:getGreetingResponse xmlns:ns2="http://wsserver.myfirst.com/">
 <return>Hello Cheepu</return>
  </ns2:getGreetingResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Result in the XML is "Hello Cheepu". How can i retrieve that from the response.

Comment: it depends, which language and library are you using?

Comment: The answer given below assumes that you are doing the work in JavaScript at the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may load the XML DOM with code such as:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
  }
```

Then traverse the DOM to the  element. 
This code is for javaScrip at the browser. Similar code in Java as given in http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/